# Checking whether Network IF can access Internet in C Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a simple library for checking the internet access status of network interfaces by C on Linux.

- Checking the status for all network interfaces (configured or not configured)

Would you please give me where i can refer ( such as documents, example code ...) or any hints?

Comment: You'll need to define some heuristic for accessibility. Even if you have an enabled interface which appears to have an available route, there could be an upstream firewall blocking any connection attempts. Perhaps actually attempt connecting to a known IP?

Comment: My need is: 
- Checking Linux PC can connect to a host or address (yahoo.com) successfully.
How to check an available route?

Comment: Why not just try connecting? If that's what you want to do, that's the most reliable test. It seems unnecessary to parse routing tables and guess at whether or not a connection may be possible when you can just try it. If you want to test yahoo.com, just try to open a socket on port 80.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I want check connection with many method. The program can select which method and network interface for checking. So, i want to know all methods to determine which methods will be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is probably to check for the existence of a default route through that interface.  You could call out to `/bin/ip route` to do this.

Comment: Can you explain more about this? I intend to use pipe with "route" to determine but how to check the result?

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11047286
The example command in this page have 0 result. I tested on my PC. My PC can access internet but the result is "0".